# Is it possible to dual-boot my TF201 with Windows RT?

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer, windows, operating-system, dual-boot

I'm really liking the look of Windows 8 / Windows RT, and I'd like to try ditching my PC entirely by getting Windows onto my Transformer Prime. I'm aware that there are a few issues around things like not having the windows key, but I can't find much conclusive information around the dual-booting situation. Most of what I've found is a from much earlier this year, and a lot of the information seems to be based on supposition rather than "*I've tried this and it did / didn't work*".

Is it, or is it not, *actually possible* to get Windows RT running well on the TF201?

As a follow-up, will Windows recognise the keyboard, or will it be ignored because it's not the Touch Cover?

Comment: Asking for Windows 8 RT support is slightly out of scope here. (See also the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq))

Comment: It's not so much WinRT support - I just want to know what the device is capable of. Looking at the FAQ, my "problem" is mainly a question of Specs. 

There seem to be plenty of questions regarding how to get Android onto to other hardware, so I'm just looking at this from the other direction.

I don't really see anything in the FAQ that disqualifies this (not being indignant - I _genuinely_ don't see anything that clearly counts this out). Still, if it's not right for this community, then I'll close this and look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows RT is based on entirely different system altogether - right from the *bootloader* up to user interface.

Also, Windows RT is proprietary so there is a fat chance that the code would be available to make it work.

What about:

- booting mechanism
- kernel
- drivers for the chip-set support

There's far too many to mention, and quite possibly would require a re-write for it to adapt to the Asus TF02! :)

This is equivalent to asking if Apple iOS can be loaded on a Android handset and vice versa, in plain simple word, the answer is No - nigh on impossible and there would be so much hackery to get it to work, let alone boot.

Answer (score 0):

no, it is not. A Windows RT bootloader would have to be leaked and customised for the TF201, would like to see it as well though ;-)